# eclipse tfs plugin won't connect to tfs server

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

We have the TFS server installed and running at `http://myhost:8080/tfs/web/`.
I've installed the Eclipse TFS plugin and updated Eclipse to 4.2
However, when I try to add a TFS server in the Team Explorer perspective, I get "The server myhost failed to respond"
How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the answer. It's because "Cisco AnyConnect Web Security Agent" was running on my machine. I turned it off and now the TFS plugin is working.

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse has some issues with the default proxy detection.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections and set Proxy to anything other than Native.

You can choose Direct, but you'll have issues if you need to perform software updates or installation.  Or you can choose Manual and configure your proxy settings manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we don't have proxy servers here, so I can't use Manual. Tried Direct and no luck there either.

Comment: Interesting!  Mind bringing this over to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/tee where we can dive a little deeper?

Comment: (Alternately, you could post the relevant details of your Team Explorer Everywhere log files in your question...  They're in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Team Foundation\4.0\Logs`...  Whichever you prefer!)

Comment: There is no Team Foundation subdirectory.

Comment: Pardon me, I misspoke.  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Logs`.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm glad for your help. Found the log files, but they're all empty files. The file names are teamexplorer-soap-plugin-2013.03.06-17.30.15.log and teamexplorer-plugin-2013.03.06-17.30.15.log

Comment: That's disappointing - I assume you have mylyn installed and that they haven't yet fixed this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=353168

Comment: I do not have mylyn installed.

Comment: I take it back. It looks like I have Mylyn installed, but I've never used it. Shall I remove it?

Comment: That should allow us to write our log files - it would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, THAT was painful. Got the contents though. From the soap-plugin log:
2013-03-07 14:43:33,644 SOAP method='Connect', status=-1, content-length=-1, server-wait=-1 ms, parse=16557 ms, total=16556 ms, throughput=0 B/s, uncompressed
2013-03-07 14:43:49,684 SOAP method='Connect', status=-1, content-length=-1, server-wait=-1 ms, parse=16029 ms, total=16028 ms, throughput=0 B/s, uncompressed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25814/discussion-between-gary-kephart-and-edward-thomson)

Comment: I was receiving a 503 error and used this solution to disable the proxy settings I added so that Eclipse could do updates.  It seems to have worked.  How can I get updates and TFS connectivity to coexist?

Comment: @gonzobrains I think you'll need to specify your accurate proxy settings in the 'Manual' setting.

Comment: I have proxy settings that work for connecting to get updates, but I had to disable them in order to connect to TFS with the plugin.

Comment: @gonzobrains: It sounds like your TFS server has not been added to your proxy exclusion list.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Is that a setting I can changed within Eclipse?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Is it the "proxy bypass" settings?

Comment: @gonzobrains - Yes, you'll want to bypass the proxy to hit your TFS server, so you'll need to add your TFS server to that list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL of `http://myhost:8080/tfs` in your server connection page rather than `http://myhost:8080/tfs/web/`?